# ¿como introducir información de un datatable a una tabla en SQLite en c# VS Xamarin?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

En C# para Visual Studio Xamarin.
Así captura información desde un archivo CSV a un Datatable.
DataTable dtCSV = new DataTable();
        string cargaArchivo = "";

```
    public DataTable CargarDataCSV(string nombreArchivo)
    {
        //Los datos van separados en 5 columnas
        dtCSV.Columns.Add("Columna1", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dtCSV.Columns.Add("Columna2", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dtCSV.Columns.Add("Columna3", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dtCSV.Columns.Add("Columna4", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dtCSV.Columns.Add("Columna5", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dtCSV.Columns.Add("Columna6", Type.GetType("System.String"));

        string path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal).ToString();
        cargaArchivo = path +"/"+ nombreArchivo;

        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(cargaArchivo).Select(a => a.Split(','));

        foreach (var ae in lines)
        {
            dtCSV.Rows.Add(ae.ToString());
        }

        return dtCSV;
```

Ahora quiero introducir está Datatablet a una tabla de SQLite.
Alguien me puede indicar como se puede hacer esto mandando cada elemento a la tabla respetando la estructura de las 6 columnas

Answer (score 0):

Debes seguir unos pasos para disponer primero de Sqlite en tu proyecto Xamarin y después hacer uso de los métodos para crear tablas y grabar registros.

En este enlace tienes información importante
https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/databases/sqlite/